# How to hide/show particular block for specific profile user in Lightning component

Tags: lightning

we written logic to provide upload option to upload documents into sales force from community portal. Now only admin user should able to see that option, for other users Upload option should not be visible.
Please find the below screen shot, I want to hide Upload files or drop files section for Non Admin users. Please help me how can i do that.
[image]

My Component Code:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.customers}" var="cus" indexVar="key">

    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:download" variant="bare" alternativeText="Settings"/>
    <a style="color: #000000"  href="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+cus.key}" target="_blank" preview="{!cus.value}">{!cus.value}</a>
    <br></br> 
</aura:iteration>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.inputshow}">
    <lightning:input aura:id="filenameid" label="Content Title" style="width:25%" required="true"/>
</aura:if> 

<lightning:input aura:id="fileId" onchange="{!c.handleFilesChange}" type="file" name="file" label="Upload Attachment" multiple="false"/>
<div class="slds-text-body_small slds-text-color_error">{!v.fileName} </div>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.buttonshow}">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.doSave}">Upload Attachment</button>
</aura:if> 
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showLoadingSpinner}">
    <div class="slds-text-body_small slds-text-color_error">Uploading... 
        <img src="/auraFW/resources/aura/images/spinner.gif" class="spinner-img" alt="Loading"/>'
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: Have you tried getting current user information and putting that block in if condition for that profile(Admin)?

Comment: Yes tried got User profile from Apex controller and tried to add logic in existing doinit method, if profile name equalts to "System Admin" making boolen attribute as true and checking that in aura if, but it is imapacting existing functionality in do int method. Please help me on this